# Infinite tensor product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Recently while reading an article I came across the usage of infinite tensor product of Hilbert spaces. I have got a basic understanding of doing computations in infinite tensor product while reading the article as it mostly involved elementary tensors, but I am curious to know the exact construction of such a tensor product and the inner product that is given on the infinite tensor product. It would be of great help to me if anyone gives a reference or an explanation of such a construction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without making the question more specific, it looks like a duplicate. In addition to the question linked above, the topic also came up [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211082).